# Blazor WASM - @foreach cannot operate on variable Task<IEnumerable> because Task<IEnumerable<ModuleDto>> doesn't contain a public instance

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using Blazor Web Assembly and i'm trying to display a Section Header with its Section Content.

```
 int sectionId;

@foreach (var item in Sections)
{
                //Display Section Name
    <h2>@item.SectionName</h2>

    //Get ID For Section Content
    sectionId = item.Id;

    @foreach (var content in GetContent(sectionId))
    {

    }

}
```

But i'm getting the following error on the GetContent(id) Method.

Error - @foreach cannot operate on variable Task because Task<IEnumerable> doesn't contain a public instance

In my component base class, the function is returning a IEnumerable collection of the DTO.

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ModuleContentDto>> GetContent(int sectionId)
    {
        
        var content = await ModuleService.GetContent(sectionId);

        return content;
    }
```

Service Class

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ModuleContentDto>> GetContent(int sectionId)
    {
        var response = await this.httpClient.GetAsync($"api/Module/{sectionId}/GetItems");

        try
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
                {
                    return Enumerable.Empty<ModuleContentDto>();
                }

                return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<ModuleContentDto>>();
            }
            else
            {
                var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                throw new Exception($"Http status code: {response.StatusCode} message: {message}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

but I cant iterate over the collection in my razor component? Please can someone suggest the best way to do it as iv tried converting to a LIST and a ENumerator.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate problem is that you do not `await` your task. That should be a simple fix.

However, you should really not mix `Task` and `IEnumerable`. Asyncronous execution *and* deferred execution in the same method is really a bug waiting to happen. If you want to execute this `async` then pick a materialized collection, like a `List<>` or simply an array as your return type.

Comment: Hey, thanks for coming back. Where can you see that i dont have an await? Thanks,

Comment: `var content in GetContent(sectionId)` is missing an `await` because `GetContent` is returning a `Task<>`.

Answer (score 1):

`GetContent` is `async` and returning a `Task`. However, you are calling it without `await` in your `@foreach`.

You need to call `GetContent` in the `@code` section of your razor page, for example in `OnInitializedAsync()` and store your `IEnumerable<ModuleContentDto>` in a variable. Then you can iterate with foreach.

```
@foreach (var item in Sections)
{
    //Display Section Name
    <h2>@item.SectionName</h2>

    //Get ID For Section Content
    @{
      int sectionId = item.Id;
    }

    @if(ModuleContentDtoDict.ContainsKey(sectionId))
    {
      @foreach (var content in ModuleContentDtoDict[sectionId])
      {

      }
    }

}

@code{
  public Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<ModuleContentDto>> ModuleContentDtoDict { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<ModuleContentDto>>();

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    foreach(var item in Sections)
    {
      int sectionId = item.Id;
      IEnumerable<ModuleContentDto> moduleContentDtoList = await GetContent(sectionId);
      ModuleContentDtoDict.Add(sectionId, moduleContentDtoList);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for coming back with this. The only issue i have with this is that im using a nested @foreach loop, whereby i get the section name and the id, then i call the GetContent(int sectionId) to get that sections content (there is multiple content within a section) so i cant use the OnInitializedAsync() because im calling that function once iv entered the for loop. Does that make sense? I'll amend my code in the question above so its clearer.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant in the last part. You should be able to iterate over Sections and store your lists in something (for example a `Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<ModuleContentDto>>` having the `sectionId` has a key).

Comment: I edited my answer for a nested @foreach.

Comment: Thanks for doing this, I'm new to Blazor and c# so ill take a further look at dictionary's. Thanks again